# $H$ Hilbert space, $T$ symmetric bounded linear, when is $H=R(T) \oplus N(T)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, direct-sum

I just saw in an exercise that if I have a prehilbert space $H$ and $T$ a linear, bound and symmetric operator then $R(T)=N(T)^{\perp}$. Now I was asking myself whether $H=R(T) \oplus N(T)$.
On [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement#Properties_2) I saw that if $X$ is closed in $H$ then $H=X \oplus X^{\perp}$.
So the question is, is $R(T)$ or $N(T)$ closed in general? Is $N(T)$ closed if it is separable?

Answer (score 4):

The kernel of a bounded linear operator is always closed (it's the preimage of the closed set $\{0\}$ under a continuous map). The range may or may not be closed. In fact, the closedness of $R(T)$ is equivalent to $R(T)=N(T)^\perp$, which you wrongfully claim to hold in general.

In my experience, the most useful criterion for closedness of $R(T)$ comes in the form of an abstract Poincaré inequality: The range of $T$ is closed if and only if there exists $c>0$ such that
$$
\|Tx\|\geq c\|x\|
$$
for all $x\in N(T)^\perp$.

Comment: Just curious, do you have an example of a bounded linear map $T : H \to H$ on an incomplete inner product space $H$ such that $R(T)$ is closed but $H \ne R(T) \oplus N(T)$?

Comment: @MaoWao Oh, right, if T is bounded and linear it is continuous so the preimage of the closed set $\{0\}$ is also closed. But also, I claimed $R(T)=N(T)^{\perp}$ if T is symmetric linear and bounded. Isn't this true?

Comment: @roi_saumon As I said, the equality $R(T)=N(T)^\perp$ holds for a symmetric bounded linear operator if and only if $R(T)$ is closed. Remember that the orthogonal complement of a set is always closed.

Comment: @mechanodroid Not off the top of my head, no. I will think about it.

Comment: Interestingly, it seems in that such a map cannot exist. Namely, we can always extend $T$ uniquely to a bounded linear map $\overline{T} : \overline{H} \to \overline{H}$ where $\overline{H}$ is the completion of $H$.
We then have $R(\overline{T}) = \overline{R(T)}$ where the closure is taken in $\overline{H}$. Hence $\overline{H} = \overline{R(T)} \oplus N(\overline{T})$ so 
$$H = H \cap \overline{H} = H \cap \left(\overline{R(T)} \oplus N(\overline{T})\right) = \left(H \cap \overline{R(T)}\right) \oplus \left(H \cap N(\overline{T})\right) = R(T) \oplus N(T)$$

Comment: @mechanodroid This is not true. Why should $R(\bar T)=\overline {R(T)}$? Take $H=C([0,1])$ with $L^2$-inner product, completion is $L^2$. Let $(Tx)(t)=tx(t)$. This operator does not have closed range neither on $H$ nor on $\bar H$.

Comment: @daw You're right, I was too quick to conclude $R(\bar T)=\overline {R(T)}$, I can only show $R(\bar T)\subseteq\overline {R(T)}$. However, your example doesn't have a closed range in $H$ so it is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @daw Btw how do you show that your $T$ doesn't have closed range on $H$? For $\overline{H}$ I know that $\sigma(T) = \sigma_c(T) = [0,1]$ so in particular $R(T)$ is not closed in $\overline{H}$.

Comment: @mechanodroid: the function $z(t)=t^{3/4}$ is in $\overline {R(T)}$ btu not in $R(T)$: as $Tf_n \to z$ for $f_n(t) = \max(n,t^{-1/4})$.